# PHP XML-RPC server return code/error do not show in Perl XML-RPC client

Tags: php, xml, perl, xml-rpc

I am having a strange issue with XML-RPC.

I need to use an existing commercial XML-RPC API, written in PHP (extremely poorly, I must add, with horrible documentation), from a Perl script. I have tried with all Perl XML-RPC modules i could find (`Frontier::Client`, `XML::RPC`, `RPC::XML`), but generally this happens:

- When my call is successful, i get the result, nothing wrong.
- When it isn't (for whatever reason - failed authentication, missing/wrong parameters), i get nothing. An empty response(when using Frontier::Client, it says 500 Internal Server Error), without any error code/message.
- But when I use the PHP test file the vendor of the commercial API have sent me, using the same methods and parameters, I get a response code and a response message(rarely useful, but nonetheless).

What could be the explanation of that? The library they use on the server side outputs the errors in some weird way? (Note: I think they use xmlrpc-2.2.2, at least that's what's used on the client side in the test PHP file). This is an example XML response with an error I get from the PHP client.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<methodResponse>
    <params>
        <param>
        <value>
            <struct>
                <member>
                    <name>demande</name>
                    <value>
                        <struct>
                            <member>
                                <name>0</name>
                                <value>
                                    <struct>
                                        <member>
                                            <name>codeReponse</name>
                                            <value>
                                                <int>-28</int>
                                            </value>
                                        </member>
                                        <member>
                                            <name>messageReponse</name>
                                            <value>
                                                <string>Verifiez l&apos;adresse email de validation</string>
                                            </value>
                                        </member>
                                    </struct>
                                </value>
                            </member>
                        </struct>
                    </value>
                </member>
            </struct>
        </value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodResponse>
```

It's in French, but you would get the gist. Why does that appear properly in the PHP, but not in my Perl script, whatever library I use? And is there any way to remedy this, without telling the vendor of the API to rewrite their code properly?

Comment: We would need to see some code to have a chance to answer I think.

Comment: Can you get the raw XML out of the API?

Comment: As i tried to point out, the code is kinda irrelevant. I don't have access to the API's code, and mine is nothing but simple call methods(from three different modules).
As for the test PHP script, it also contains the simplest possible declaration of the client, bind of parameters, and call.
The output XML from both scripts is almost identical(a few newline characters more in the PHP-generated XML, but i really don't think that matters)

Comment: Furthermore, i have tried posting the data outputted by the PHP script(which works) with CURL, and still no luck - empty response.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out that the XML-RPC server is pretty picky and requires a set of headers and cookies to work(most of whom useless), otherwise it just outputs nothing.